# Why does pygame set the title icon to the python runtime icon?

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.9

When I try to set a pygame window's icon to a png, it sets it to the python console icon. I'm very rusty from not doing pygame a lot, but this doesn't seem to happen to other people. I use pygame 2.1.2 and python 3.9.7, if it helps.

Here is the code to my program:

```py
import pygame
from time import sleep as wait
from os.path import join as path
from random import choice
from pygame.locals import MOUSEBUTTONDOWN, KEYDOWN, BUTTON_LEFT, K_a, K_d, K_w, QUIT
from threading import Thread
image_start = "images"

pygame.init()

icon = pygame.image.load(path(image_start, "icon.png"))

win = pygame.display.set_mode(size=(1200, 800))
pygame.display.set_caption("8 Hours At Nova Willow's")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

nova_willow = pygame.image.load(path(image_start, "nova_willow.png"))
camera = pygame.image.load(path(image_start, "camera.png"))
camoverlay = pygame.image.load(path(image_start, "camoverlay.png"))
camoverlay.set_alpha(146)
static1 = pygame.image.load(path(image_start, "static1.png"))
static1.set_alpha(146)
static2 = pygame.image.load(path(image_start, "static2.png"))
static2.set_alpha(146)
static3 = pygame.image.load(path(image_start, "static3.png"))
static3.set_alpha(146)
x = 0
y = 0
static = [static1, static2, static3, static2, static3, static1]

#Note: KEYDOWN only activates at the beginning of a key press, Same for MOUSEBUTTONDOWN, just for the mouse

cameraon = False
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit(0)
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_w:
                cameraon = not cameraon
    # if floor(staticindex) == 
    staticChoice = choice(static)
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    if cameraon:
        win.blit(camera, (x, y))
        win.blit(staticChoice, (0, 0))
        win.blit(camoverlay, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
    
    wait(0.01)
```

There are no errors in this, but the icon isn't what I want it to be.

Comment: Pygame 2.0.1 is quite old. The current version is 2.1.2.

Comment: Some operating systems don't support changing the icon after the window is created. Place the line with `set_icon` thus before the one with `set_mode`.

Comment: I'm attempting both

Comment: Nothing i try is working, I'm just gonna give up...

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce - when I run your code (I stripped out everything except creating a window and setting the icon) I do in fact get the correct icon in both the title bar and the taskbar.

Comment: What Operating System are you running on? What are the dimensions of your image? If I try a large image, `set_icon(…)` silently fails. The [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_icon) say around 32x32 pixels for the image size.

Comment: thanks @importrandom, i was using a bigger image then 32x32, so you've been a code savor!

Comment: Glad to hear your problem has been resolved. You can create and accept your [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) which might help future discoverers of this question who don't desperately delve into the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is because of your old version, but I don't think so. To set your caption you put `pygame.display.set_caption("")` but for your icon you put `win.set_icon(icon)`

In my current project (I am on 2.1.2), I use `pygame.display.set_icon(icon)` to set my icon instead.

This format matches your `set_caption` function so I think it might work, lmk!

Comment: I have tried that, but unfortunately it did not work, thank you for trying to help me though.